# Database mail messed up CSV attachment

Tags: sql-server, dbmail

Is there any way to format output CSV from below statement to be easily readable by Excel? As for now it opens all columns messed up into one column. I have tried already different deperators.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'auto-reporting'
  , @recipients = @recipientsList   
  , @subject = 'MC Auto Reports'
  , @query = 'select * from test.dbo.temp'
  , @attach_query_result_as_file = 1
  , @query_result_separator =','
  , @query_result_no_padding = 1
  , @query_attachment_filename = @FileName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to edit produced .csv file in notepad. In the very first line type [sep=,] without quotes and save it. Then try to open it in Excel if its correctly displayed then you need to check your regional settings in windows.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
, @query_result_separator =','
```

to

```
, @query_result_separator = @separator
```

Just add this code before sending the email

```
DECLARE @separator CHAR(1)
SET @separator = CHAR(9)
```

This makes the seperator TAB which Excel likes better.